# Javascript navigator.mediasession cover art not showing in navi

Tags: javascript, navigator, mediasession

it's me again with my audio player. This is kinda a continuation of my previous question... (link [here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71823496/javascript-navigator-mediasession-image-not-showing-in-navigator-media-control)

Along with my question above, i've been tinkering with the song title/artist/thumbnail metadata, and I've succeeded with the title and artist. But for some reason, I can't seem to figure out how to display the thumbnail. I've looked at every guide and all, but the only thing I can find that's different between our codes is the fact that I don't have the image sizes specified. Now, I have a genuine reason for this, which is that I have inconsistent image sizes and thus cannot add the sizes (I have tried, with EVERY size used specified, never worked!)

Can someone tell me any alternatives to this or how to fix this (in a way that doesn't need me to go on a 5 hour montage editing the sizes of 118 images)?

Comment: Ok, Basically you dont have images not of a specific size? Have you tried using a size parameters in the image tag using css?

Comment: For Example specifying the `width` `height` and `aspect-ratio` for an image tag?

Comment: You don't need to specify the `sizes`, it's just an optional hint (same for `type` btw): https://jsfiddle.net/06a3qy4r/ However it seems that Chrome does have an internal limit as to the size of the image they accept (regardless of the `sizes` value). Any image that has **both** the width and height below 114px will not be shown (don't ask why). Maybe you are in this case? Otherwise look at the Network tab of your dev-tools to check if the image is located properly by the browser.

Comment: I think my problem is the fact that I'm using local files... but if I don't that means I'll have to find a way to put the image files online which I'm not sure how to do, and google drive doesn't seem to be a good option.

Comment: @Kaiido OMG that's literally my whole problem! I've been using files with large sizes, thank you so much!!!